# Displaying an image

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using vb.net running a backend MS.Access database and I am wondering what is the code that I can use to display a picture of an image when the field name is selected.

My MS Access "field" name is Cars_Types:  in the files I have the data "GM, Chrysler, Toyota, Honda, and Ford".

The name of my database is `ModelCars.accdb`

The pictures are not coded into the database instead I would like them to be coded into the VB.NET program.

I have the database working correctly within my VB.NET program but I am having trouble getting the images to appear.

Comment: This question has nothing substantive to do with MS-ACCESS. The tags really aren't helpful, though of course, it's appropriate to mention Access in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have the five images or so, you could store them in your .NET application as local [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytt371w5%28VS.80%29.aspx). When you retrieve an associated record from the database, display it (in whatever context you need, I copied the msdn example here):

```
Me.Background= My.Resources.GMImage
```

**Edit:** To select which image to use, if you have a string in the DB of the various car types, just use a switch statement:

```
Select Case(carType)
    Case "GM": me.picCarPhotos = My.Resources.GMImage
    Case "Ford": me.picCarPhotos = My.Resources.FordImage
End Select
```

*Disclaimer: I'm more familiar with C# so this may need some tweaking if my VB is off.*

Comment: Okay, I think I have it, for me since I have already created the picture box on my form it would be this way.

me.picCarPhotos = My.Resources.GMImage.

But how do you call the field "Car_Type" Data "Ford" to match the image in my recources bin FordFocus.jpg

Comment: The easiest way that I can think of would just be to use a switch statement. I'll edit the answer with that code.